# How to incorporate multiple collection views in one view controller?

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, uicollectionview

[image: Multiple Collection Views]

I am trying to get seven horizontal scrollable button bars using UICollectionViews. I have no problem getting one button bars up and running, but I run into app crashing errors when I use multiple Collection Views. Does anybody have any idea how to get this going in Swift or know of any tutorials? My code for the first Collection View is here:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, UICollectionViewDataSource, UICollectionViewDelegate {

    var tableImages: [String] = ["1.png", "2.png", "3.png", "4.png", "5.png", "6.png"]

    func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return tableImages.count
    }

    func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        let cell:CollectionViewCell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier("cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! CollectionViewCell
        cell.expansionCell.image = UIImage(named: tableImages[indexPath.row])
        return cell
    }

    func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
        println("cell \(indexPath.row) selected")
    }
}
```

Please help!

Comment: What are the errors you're getting? And on which line?

Comment: There are a lot of tutorial putting UICollectionView in UITableViewCell, so make a UITableView that contains UICollectionView and you can get multiple UICollectionView in UITableView, http://ashfurrow.com/blog/putting-a-uicollectionview-in-a-uitableviewcell/

Comment: I get Thread 1 signal SIGABRT.

Comment: On which line are you getting that error?

Comment: Start here: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/recipes/xcode_help-breakpoint_navigator/articles/adding_an_exception_breakpoint.html.  This is a non-question without an explanation of the error.

Comment: Yeah this is an interesting questions.... I am not sure if its possible to run from a single collectionview without adding a performance overhead.

Answer (score 1):

To separate the logic, you could create 3 data source objects to populate the collection views. Each data source can handle all of the cell logic for its collection view. This will make your view controller less confusing as all you have to do is assign them all in `viewDidLoad`. You will need to keep a reference to the data source objects since `collectionView.dataSource` will not.

```
var collectionViewA: UICollectionView!
var dataSourceA: DataSourceA!
var collectionViewB: UICollectionView!
var dataSourceB: DataSourceB!
var collectionViewC: UICollectionView!
var dataSourceC: DataSourceC!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    self.dataSourceA = DataSourceA()
    self.collectionViewA.dataSource = self.dataSourceA
    // repeat for dataSource/collectionView B and C
}
```

Comment: Excellent advice, but almost certainly unrelated to the OP's problem.

Comment: That was my up-vote, but your comment muddles the otherwise good advice.  Its nice design to have separate instances (even classes) for datasources, but their execution is serialized on the main thread.  Not sure what you mean by "resource crash"?  And what are a few of the myriad of problems stemming from the code?  From what I see, it looks like the OP will have three collections presenting the same set of images.  Your -- still good -- original suggestion will save the OP the conditional logic he/she will need to distinguish the views.

Answer (score 0):

This is how I did my case. hope it will help you.

outlets:

```
@IBOutlet weak var collectionView: UICollectionView!
@IBOutlet weak var SecondCollectioView: UICollectionView!
```

Method:

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "customCell", for: indexPath) as UICollectionViewCell

    if(collectionView == self.SecondCollectioView) {
        cell.backgroundColor = UIColor.black
    } else {
         cell.backgroundColor = self.randomColor()
    }

    return cell;
}
```

Comment: what should we write if ReuseIdentifier of collection views be different? please look at my question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47530933/why-two-collection-views-in-two-table-view-cells-wont-work-in-swift-4